# How to make total?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Using SQLSERVER 2000

How to make a total of intime value

```
Table 1
    InTime
    02:00:48
    22:00:22
    .....,
```

Intime Datatype is varchar

```
02:00:12 - (HH:MM:SS)
```

Before I tried in access 2003

```
select format( Int(24*sum(Intime)), '0') & format( sum(Intime) , ':ss' ) AS totaltime from table1
```

Above Query is working perfectly in Access 2003

How to make a total of Intime in sql?

Expected Output

```
Intime

24:01:00
```

So on...,

Need Query help

Comment: Are you sure inTime is a varchar ? If so, how can you sum it?

Comment: Before I make total(intime) in Access, Now it is working. How can i make a total of intime in Sql

Comment: I believe the correct result should be 24:01:10, unless you plan to always round to the nearest minute (48 + 22 = 70 seconds)...

Comment: @Gopal, what about your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498065/how-to-get-a-total-of-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
inTime varchar(8)
)

SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES('02:00:48')
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES('22:00:22')
SET NOCOUNT OFF


SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(2),TotalSeconds/3600)
        +':'
        +RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(varchar(2),(TotalSeconds-(TotalSeconds/3600*3600))/60),2)
        +':'
        +RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(varchar(2),TotalSeconds-((TotalSeconds/3600*3600)+(((TotalSeconds-(TotalSeconds/3600*3600))/60)*60))),2) AS Answer
        ,DATEADD(second,dt.TotalSeconds,CONVERT(datetime,'1/1/1900')) AS AnswerIncrementingDays

    FROM (SELECT
              SUM(DATEDIFF(second,CONVERT(datetime,'1/1/1900'),CONVERT(datetime,'1/1/1900 '+inTime))) AS TotalSeconds
              FROM #Table1
         ) dt
```

OUTPUT:

```
Answer   AnswerIncrementingDays
-------- -----------------------
24:01:10 1900-01-02 00:01:10.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Now Getting correct time, But why the query is so much long compared to Access. There is any other related query is available.

Answer (score 0):

```
select right('0' + cast(TotalHours + TotalMinutes / 60 as varchar), 2) + ':' + right('0' + cast(TotalMinutes % 60 as varchar), 2) + ':' + right('0' + cast(Seconds as varchar), 2)
from (
    select TotalHours, TotalMinutes + TotalSeconds / 60 as TotalMinutes, TotalSeconds % 60 as Seconds
    from (
        select 
            TotalHours = SUM(cast(substring(a, 1, 2) as int)),
            TotalMinutes = SUM(cast(substring(a, 4, 2) as int)),
            TotalSeconds = SUM(cast(substring(a, 7, 2) as int))
        from (
            select '02:00:48' a
            union
            select '22:00:22'
        ) a
    ) b
) c
```

Comment: Updated: added leading zeros.