# Minus of time value issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

query

```
Select id, CONVERT(char(8), CASE WHEN DateAdd(Day, - DateDiff(Day, 0, OutTime), OutTime) > Normal_Outtime THEN Cast(Normal_Outtime AS datetime) ELSE DateAdd(Day, - DateDiff(Day, 0, OutTime), OutTime) END - CASE WHEN DateAdd(Day, - DateDiff(Day, 0, InTime), InTime) < Normal_Intime THEN Cast(Normal_Intime AS datetime) ELSE DateAdd(Day, - DateDiff(Day, 0, InTime), InTime) END - cast(totalLunchtime AS datetime), 8) ELSE '00:00:00' END AS WorkedTime
from table
```

From the above query, doing outtime - intime - totallunchtime

column datatypes are varchar

Example

```
Id  |Intime   |Outtime  |totallunchtime

001 |09:00:00 |21:00:00 |01:00:00
002 |07:00:00 |07:30:00 |01:00:00
003 |00:00:00 |00:00:00 |01:00:00
```

WorkedTime means (outtime - Intime - totalLunchtime)

Getting Output like this

```
id  |workedtime

001 |11:00:00
002 |23:30:00 
003 |23:00:00
```

Only the problem of totallunchtime while minus 00:00:00 it giving 23:00:00 and also for personid 002 it giving 23:30:00 it should give only 00:30:00

Expected output

```
id  |workedtime

001 |11:00:00
002 |00:23:00
003 |00:00:00
```

so on...,

Need Query Help

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509508/how-to-make-total

Comment: Orbman. This is for Minus the timevalue problem. That one is different read the question again

Comment: @Gopal, what about all of your other time questions you have asked the last few days? there have been many questions for you to clarify what you are asking, did you ever clarify those questions, or even accept any of those answers?

Comment: The concept is exactly the same as the other question - parse a time string, do arithemtic on it, convert back to time string. You need to learn to fish...

Comment: @OrbMan, but it is so much easier taking the fish handout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this do the job?

```
declare @a datetime
declare @b datetime
declare @c datetime

set @a = '09:00:00'
set @b = '17:00:00'
set @c = '01:00:00'

select @b - @a - case when datediff(n, @a, @b) < 60 then '00:00:00' else @c end
```

If you need more than this, then you need to clarify under what conditions the totallunchtime column should be taken into account.

Comment: @Chris J said _If you need more than this, then you need to clarify..._, ha! see my comment on the question...